# Google maps wont load after debug.keystone deletion

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i had a problem with a project that said that the debug.keystone had expired and i read in stack over flow solutions that i had to delete it in order to force eclipse create a new one.

But after that my application wont load the Google map i just see the squares ... any solutions ??

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have a new keystore, you will need to generate a new MD5 fingerprint from it. When you've done that, submit that fingerprint to Google to get a new API key, then put that in your application to replace the existing one. (You must have done this process before with the old keystore if you have had Google Maps working up till now.)